# Error linking to a function in dll.. giving error of parameter changed C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc

I am trying to link a `dll library` to my current project. The library is linked and read but when i am trying to call this specific function its giving me a linker error specifying the input parameter is `unsigned uchar *` whereas i have `BYTE*` as the input parameter in the function and also on the call.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall C_projectApp::
detect(unsigned char *,struct _tagInfo *)"
```

whereas the function definition is

```
void detect(BYTE* inp_ , Blob_Info*_info)
```

Any suggestions about it ?

Comment: Is the function inside a class? BYTE is a typedef to unsigned char. So this isn't the problem. May bethe class/struct Blob_info is wrong.

Comment: I cleaned it up and checked it again it was giving me the problem there but cleaning it and compiling it in X64 environment removed the error maybe because of some external linking library.